# Problems with Memory and CPU limits in AWS ECS cluster running on reserved EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am running the ECS cluster that currently has 3 services running on T3 medium instance. Each of those services is running only one task which has a soft memory limit of 1GB, the hard limit is different for each (but that should not be the problem). I will always have enough memory to run one, new deployed task (new one will also take 1GB, and T3 medium will be able to handle it since it has 4GB total). After the new task is up and running, the old one will be stopped and I will have again 1GB free for the new deployment. I did similar to the CPU (2048 CPU, each task has 512, and 512 free for new deployments).

So everything runs fine now, but I am not completely satisfied with this setup for the future. What will happen if I need to add another service with another task? I need to deploy all existing tasks and to modify their task definitions to use less CPU and memory in order to run this new task (and new deployments). I am planning to get a reserved EC2 instance, so it will not be easy to swap the current EC2 instance with the larger one.

Is there a way to spin up another EC2 instance for the same ECS cluster to handle bursts in my tasks? Also deployments, it's not a perfect scenario to have the ability to deploy only one task, and then wait for old to be killed in order to deploy the next one, without downtimes.
And biggest concern, what if I need new service and task, I need again to adjust all others in order to run a new one and deploy others, which is not very maintainable and what if I cannot lower CPU and memory more because I already reached the lowest point in order to run the task smoothly.

I was thinking about having another EC2 instance for the same cluster, that will handle bursts, deployments, and new services/tasks. But not sure if that's possible and if that's the best way of doing this. I was also thinking about Fargate, but this is much more expensive and I cannot afford it for now. What do you think? Any ideas, suggestions, and hints will be helpful since I am desperate to find the best way to avoid the problems mentioned above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not using an autoscaling group with the cluster? How did you create your cluster? You can fine tune how you want your autoscaling group to scale and your cluster will scale in/out based on the needs so you have capacity when it's needed.

Comment: Good point, I was also thinking about this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deep-dive-on-amazon-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling/
But not 100% sure if this will fit my needs. So if I am running out of resources, ASG will spin another instance and run task inside a new one (eg. while deploying new revision of existing task). And after a new task is up, old got killed and now I have enough resources on the main instance to run that task, but the task is already running on the second instance (run by ASG). Is there a way to have the optimal distribution of tasks on a minimal number of instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unfortunately, there is no out of the box solution to ensure that all your tasks run on min possible (i.e. one) instance. You can use our new feature called [Capacity Providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html) (CP), which will allow you to ensure the minimum number of ec2 instances required to run all your tasks. The major difference between CP vs ASG is that CP gives more weight to task placement (where as ASG will scale in/out based on resource utilization which isn't ideal in your case).

However, it's not an ideal solution. Just as you said in your comment, when the service needs to scale out during a deployment, CP will spin up another instance, the new task will be placed on it and once it gets to Running state, the old task will be stopped.

But now you have an "extra" EC2 instance because there is no way to replace a running task. The only way I can think of would be to use a lambda function [that drains the](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-draining.html) *new* instance, which will move all the service tasks to the other instance. CP will, after about 15 minutes, terminate this instance as there are no tasks are running on it.

A couple caveats:

- CP are new, a little rough around the edges, and you can't
  delete/modify them. You can only create or deactivate them.
- CP needs an underlying ASG and they must have a 1-1 relationship
- Make sure to enable managed scaling when creating CP
- Choose 100% capacity target
- Don't forget to add a default capacity strategy for the cluster

Answer (score 0):

### Minimizing EC2 instances used:

If you're using a capacity provider, the 'binpack' placement strategy minimises the number of EC2 hosts that are used.

However, there are some scale-in scenarios where you can end up with a single task running on its own EC2 instance. As Ali mentions in their answer; ECS will not replace this running task, but depending on your setup, it may be fairly easy for you to replace it yourself by configuring your task to voluntarily 'quit'.

In my case; I always have at least 2 tasks running per service. So I just added some logic to my tasks' healthchecks, so they report as unhealthy after ~6 hours. ECS will spot the 'unhealthy' task, remove it from the load balancer, and spin up a replacement (according to the binpack strategy).

Note: If you take this approach; add some variation to your timeout so you're less likely to have all of your tasks expire at the same time. Something like: `expiry = now + timedelta(hours=random.uniform(5.5,6.5))`

### Sharing memory 'headspace' with soft-limits:

If you set both soft and hard memory limits; ECS will place your tasks based on the soft limit. **If your tasks' memory usage varies with usage, it's fairly easy to get your EC2 instance to start swapping.**

For example: Say you have a task defined with a soft limit of 900mb, and a hard limit of 1800mb. You spin up a service with 4 running instances. ECS provisions all 4 of these instances on a single t3.medium. Notice here that each instance thinks it can safely use up to 1800mb, when in fact there's very little free memory on the host server. When you hit your service with some traffic; each task tries to use some more memory, and your t3.medium is incapacitated as it starts swapping memory to disk. **ECS does not recover from this type of failure very well.** It notices that the task instances are no longer available, and will attempt to provision replacements, but the capacity provider is very slow to replace the swapping t3.medium.

My suggestion:

- Configure your service to auto-scale based on memory usage (this will be a percentage of your soft-limit), for example: a target memory usage of 70%
- Configure your tasks' healthchecks so that they report as unhealthy when they are nearing their soft-limit. This way, your tasks still have some headroom for quick spikes of memory usage, while giving your load balancer a chance to drain and gracefully replace tasks that are getting greedy. This is fairly easy to do by reading the value within `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes`.